# Does collection.get() in firestore has limitations?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my project, every user has a document with a field `f`. My project uses the sum of every user's `f` field frequently, probably hundred thousand times a day, and my project is planned to have millions of users.

Obviously it is not efficient to calculate the sum every time I need it, so my plan is to have an additional document to track the sum. Every time a user's `f` changed, update the sum too.

But I think roundoff error may occur after a period of time, so I plan to recalculate the sum every 24 hours or 7 days.

My problem is, if I have a million documents, does `collection.get()` still work? What about a billion? I've noticed `WriteBatch` has a 500 limit. Does `collection.get()` has limit too?

Answer (score 1):

You can get as many documents as you can fit in memory on the machine where you issued the query.  The backend will stream the results until you run out.